# Angular CRUD - Refresh UI after add/update/delete operation

Tags: angular, rest, refresh, crud

I was wondering that it is better to refresh the UI when executing an add/update/delete operation from a CRUD in Angular.

The options are as follows (for example, for delete action):

**1.** Update local variable with previously fetched data after perform the action.

```
deleteProduct(id) {
    this.productsService.deleteProduct(id).subscribe(status => {
        this.products = this.products.filter(item => item.id != id);
    });
}
```

**2.** Fetch the items again calling REST API.

```
deleteProduct(id) {
    this.productsService.deleteProduct(id).subscribe(status => {
        this.getProducts();
    });
}

getProducts() {
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
        this.products = products;
    });
}
```

This would also be applicable to add or edit, with more code obviously.

Which option is better in terms of good practices and performance? Updating variable data locally or performing a new http request to obtain updated data.

Comment: obviously first approach is better and will give you higher performance than second approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, It can depend on your project . I use the following flow in my project (client[**Angular**] should follow the server)

(Here I use ***WEB API***)

**To create** : It's better to return the created Item as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(Item item)
{
    if (everything is ok)
    {
        // resourceUrl: the address of the source that we have just created
        return Created(resourceUrl, item);
    }

    if (there is an error) {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

**To Edit** : You do not need to return any Item, you should return the status code (**400**[BadRequest], **200**[OK], **204**[NoContent] and so on) like the following :

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public ActionResult Put(Item item, int id)
{
    var existingItem = (retrive item form db based on id); 
    if (existingItem == null) {
        return BadRequest("Cannot update ...");
    } else {
        // update operation here ...
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**To delete** - you should return the status code (**400**[BadRequest], **200**[OK], **204**[NoContent] and so on)

**EDIT:**

You don't have to follow above recommendation. You can select the first suggestion in your question (**Update local variable with previously fetched data after perform the action**.) , It depends on your project.

Comment: This describes the API in order to use it in the client app, isn't? In this case, when a resource is created I could obtain the new object in the response and append it to resources array without having to perform new http request to get latest data. My question is related with the client (Angular) and how I should refresh the view (UI - client side) after perform some action (add/update/delete). 1. Updating local variable or 2. Perform new http request to retrieve latest data. Thanks for yout answer.

Comment: The question is, how do you refresh UI after perform, for example, an edit action? Updating previosly fetched data stored in a variable or calling again the REST API to retrieve latest data? My question is more related with the client side, but I understand how backend can affect the frontend. With your solution for WEB API, when you update an item, how do you refresh the UI?

Comment: your welcome ,as I told in my answer, it depends on your project , as @MoxxiManagarm said , If you have a high frequency of operations on the backend data by other users, 
It's better to refresh UI. while your project has a low frequency of operations on the backend data ,
the best way is to update previosly fetched data stored in a variable insted of calling again the REST API to retrieve latest data. 
I hope It can clear your question .

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is more preferred, it is less time consuming than the second option so low loading time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your application.

Obviously the first approach is one less api call and is faster.

But imagine you have a high frequency of operations on the backend data by other users. In that case it could be very useful to refresh the list after an operation.